# Show <html> to </html> content as homepage in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a landing page. That page have total code with header, body and footer. I want to show this code as a front page of wordpress. So how can i show it. Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: A solution might be to fill the frontpage of that wordpress blog with an iframe element and load the html inside. But that is _really_ ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a pagetemplate

It will extend your template or page by a additional style/layout, if you don't include wp_header/wp_footer it will provide a blank HTML or any given HTML inside the page template.

Redirect the domain you want to this page then.
Also this here will help you ;)

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Answer (score 0):

Just save the page as `index.html`. (If WordPress overwrites it, rewrite a redirect from index.php to `index.html` in the `.htaccess` file.)

In your `.htaccess` file, you can use this;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L,R]
```

Comment: Then you cannot use wordpress any more, since the site won't have the wordpress navigation. also I do not understand what you mean by "rewrite a redirect".

Comment: @arkascha Well, it seems Ashu Garg wants it that way.

Comment: No, the OP has not thought that far. The OP only wants to see the content inside his wordpress blog. He wrote: "as the front page of wordpress". Not "as a static page independent from wordpress".

Comment: @arkascha The OP is specifically mentioning that the landing page already has its own header, body and footer, and says he wants to show that code as the frontpage. So i think he is fully aware of what will happen.

Comment: @BBQ.   I have header footer scripts css in index.html file. So i want when user click on xyz.com then this page shows. I dont want any navigation of wordpress nothing

Comment: @AshuGarg Then why do you have a wordpress blog installed there?

Comment: I want to use some plugin functionality in backend

Comment: @AshuGarg I've added some code in my answer that will help you redirect to your landing page. Make sure you add this to your `.htaccess`  file.

Comment: @BBQ. LOL, looks like you are right! +1 Doesn't make any sense in my eyes, but hey!

Comment: @arkascha Sometimes it's not that obvious, and people might have some weird ideas, but hey, if it helps them create what they wan't ;)

Comment: @arkascha See i am going to implement not a website not a blog. I was implementing some other thing. But in page creation via HTML it showed me some reponsiveness issue. So that's why ask...